# Override page.tpl.php for a custom theme hook

Tags: theming

I have a module that's creating a custom menu callback for a page that will be designed to be a PDF download, so I want to remove the usual menus and blocks. I want to create a tpl file that is only for this page that will be used for creation of a PDF.

I created the callback here:

```
function engine_activities_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['activities-pdf/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Activities Calendar PDF',
    'page callback' => 'activities_calendar_pdf',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    'access callback' => 'activities_calendar_true',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}
```

In that function, `activities_calendar_pdf` I have `return theme('pdf_page', array('date_array' => $date_array));`, which I got from this function:

```
function engine_activities_theme(){
  return array(
    'pdf_page' =>  array(
      'template' => 'page--pdf',
      'render element' => 'page',
      'variables' => array('date_array' => array()),
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'engine_activities')
    ),
  );
}
```

This is backed up by a preprocess function in that same module:

```
function engine_activities_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook){
  if(arg(0) == "activities-pdf"){
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page__pdf";
  }
}
```

(Possibly not the most stable condition check, I know)

Finally I have a `page--pdf.tpl.php` file which is being rendered appropriately, but it's in the content section of the standard `page.tpl.php` file. I want `page--pdf.tpl.php` to be rendered instead of `page.tpl.php`.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: which variable do you want to be printed in tpl.. $page or $content variable??

Comment: @PravinAjaaz There's no specific variable I want to print... I'd like to print everything in page--pdf.tpl.php